# LinkedIn issue sharing : Remove your attachment to post from another account

Tags: linkedin-api, share

I would like to use the LinkedIn share dialog to post a url to a company page. So I've included this hyperlink in my page :

```
<a th:href="'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+ ${#httpServletRequest.requestURL} +'&title=&summary='+#{share.subject}+'&source='" class="buttons buttons--linkedin" target="_blank"></a>
```

Unfortunately, when I select "share in a post" and select my company page, it says:
"Remove your attachment to post from another account." However, I can share this content via my private profile...

Is it possible to post a URL to a company page with the share dialog?

Thanks.

Comment: similar issue https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/issues/275

Comment: Was any update found on this?

Is this a linkedin limitation?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to do this is to:

1. copy the url for the page you want to post from the address bar
2. start a new post from your company page
3. paste the copied url into the draft of the new post. (linked in will render it in a few seconds)
4. finish editing your post and then post it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not ideal as it doesn't allow you to enable your users/visitors to do the same. It appears to be a bug with LinkedIn: https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/issues/275